# How to pass array value from one class to other class

Tags: iphone

How can i pass an array value from a delegate class to view controller class

```
const char *query2=[tempQuery UTF8String];
NSMutableArray *arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query2,-1,&statement1,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
    //NSLog(@"vt", vt);

    while (sqlite3_step(statement1)==SQLITE_ROW) {
        vt=[[[Question1 alloc]init]autorelease];
        vt.question=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement1,3)];
        [arr1 addObject:vt.question];
        NSLog(@"arr1 is %@",[arr1 description]);
```

Where arr1 is an array value. So that array value has to pass in another class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done any research on this? read developer.apple.com ?

Comment: @user801222: Refer to my answer. That is what exactly you want. Let me know, if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

In a class where you want to pass this "arr1" array do following steps: 
1) define a array there (lets say it is aryTest) 
2) make property for it
3) synthesize it

Now in a view where you are getting this "arr1" array.
From this view when ever you write code to push to next view do following steps:

```
NextViewController *objVc = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
objVc.aryTest = arr1;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```

so by this you will get this arr1 array into next view in aryTest array.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `NSString` or `NSMutableArray` using `NSUserDefault` method...
[NSUserDefaultExample](http://codeexamples.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/nsuserdefaults-example/)   and  [Saving/Retrieving Data Using NSUserDefaults](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/)

For Saving

```
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSString
[prefs setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

 // saving an NSInteger
 [prefs setInteger:42 forKey:@"integerKey"];

 // saving a Double
 [prefs setDouble:3.1415 forKey:@"doubleKey"];

 // saving a Float
 [prefs setFloat:1.2345678 forKey:@"floatKey"];

  // saving an array
  NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
  [prefs setObject:data forKey:@"lastResults"]

 // This is suggested to synch prefs, but is not needed (I didn't put it in my tut)
 [prefs synchronize];
```

For Retrieving

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// getting an NSString
NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

// getting an NSInteger
NSInteger myInt = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];

// getting an Float
float myFloat = [prefs floatForKey:@"floatKey"];

// getting an array
 NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray = [prefs objectForKey:@"lastResults"];
 if (dataRepresentingSavedArray != nil)
 {
    NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
    if (oldSavedArray != nil)
            objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
    else
            objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 }
```

or

```
filename *detailViewController = [[filename alloc] initWithNibName:@"filename" bundle:nil];
detailViewController.audio=@"yourData";
[self presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

Declare in filename.h

```
 NSArray *audio;

 @property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *audio;
```

and filename.m

```
 @synthesize audio;
```

thats all.

Answer (score 0):

just create a  **Array** method like in **+(NSMutableArray *)getData** in delegate class

```
+(NSMutableArray *)getData
{
const char *query2=[tempQuery UTF8String];
NSMutableArray *arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query2,-1,&statement1,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
    //NSLog(@"vt", vt);

    while (sqlite3_step(statement1)==SQLITE_ROW) {

        [arr1 addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement1,3)]];
        NSLog(@"arr1 is %@",[arr1 description]);
}
}
return [arr1 autorelease];
}
```

in your view controller just call the method like

```
 NSMutableArray * data=[[delegate getData]retain];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the array in your appDelegate. Thus it can be accessible in any view controller by calling your appDelegate:

```
myAppDelegate *myDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
arrayInView = [myDelegate msgFilter];
```